# Call custom methods using reflection in the setter methods of a jackson mapped class

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

In a spring application, I am receiving a JSON request which is being mapped to a POJO using the default deserializer. The class looks like below:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.class)
public class ParamModel implements Serializable {

    private String fieldOne;

    private String fieldTwo;

    private String fieldThree;

    // setters and getters

}
```

I am also performing custom validations (statically imported) that might change the values in the setters:

```
public String getFieldOne() {
    return fieldOne;
}

public void setFieldOne(String fieldOne) {
    this.fieldOne = fixFieldOne(fieldOne);
}

// similar getters and setters for other fields
```

The validation method names are always in the format like fix{FieldName_in_PascalCase} like fixFieldOne().

I have a class that contains the validation methods:

```
public class Validate {
    public static String fixFieldOne(String fieldOne) {
        // do stuff to fieldOne
        return fieldOne;
    }

    // validation methods for other fields
}
```

I want to do something like writing a custom deserializer:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.class)
@SomeAnnotation(using = Validation.class)
public class ParamModel implements Serializable {
    // fields, setters and getters
    // not calling the validation methods explicitly from setters anymore
}
```

So that, it will call respective validation methods from the name (say I can write a class that will take a name and resolve the proper method name from validation class) before the setter actually sets value, and I don't have to manually call the methods in each setters. Because most of the time, setters and getters are generated using some auto completion tool provided by the IDE, and it gets tedious when fields keep increasing.

Also, what is the generally accepted practice in this scenarios, when there are like around a hundred fields.

Comment: sounds like a good design to me.  is that the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @sharonbn I am hoping to see what others have to say. Don't want to write a custom annotation for this.